# comic sans in different font sizes, and updmap ? [update 3]

Tags: fontsize

[update #3 --- problem is with updmap?]

### Installation Procedure

I installed comicsans via comicsans.tds.zip.  a replay of my installation process is:

```
# sudo bash
# wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/fonts/comicsans.tds.zip
# wget http://www.fontsupply.com/fonts/COMICBD.TTF  # doesn't work, but you get the idea
# wget http://www.fontsupply.com/fonts/COMIC.TTF  # same thing
# cd /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
# unzip ~/comicsans.tds.zip
# mkdir -p fonts/truetype/microsoft/comic
# cp ~/COMIC.TTF fonts/truetype/microsoft/comic/comic.ttf
# cp ~/COMICBD.TTF fonts/truetype/microsoft/comic/comicbd.ttf
# mktexlsr
# ## WRONG updmap-sys --enable Map=/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/comicsans/comicsans.map 
   ## be careful: the word "Map" is case sensitive.
   ## instead, use updmap-sys --enable Map=comicsans.map # see below
# cd ~ ; texhash ; mktexlsr
# ls -l `kpsewhich comic.ttf`
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root 126364 Apr 22 15:06 /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/truetype/microsoft/comic/comic.ttf
```

I misunderstood the original purpose of comicsans.sty .  At this point, the comic sans fonts are available for (sparing) use, e.g., as headline fonts.  You should only usepage comicsans.sty if you want to redefine the document default fonts to use comicsans.

### Running Attempt

I read the installation documents on how to select comicsans, and it works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{comicsans}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\comicfont}{\fontfamily{comic}\selectfont}
\comicfont  %% \huge
Thanks, Scott, for making this.
\end{document}
```

On one computer it worked, but not on another.  On both, uncomment the \huge (or use a different font size), and it fails:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 2+293/600 --dpi 1493 rcomic8r
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for rcomic8r.
mktexpk: perhaps rcomic8r is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

The point (pun!) of the comic font for me is to make headlines, so I need these different size versions (a bigger font).

### updmap is wrong

Here is something I now learned:

```
# updmap
...
updmap [ERROR]: The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
updmap [ERROR]:     /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/comicsans/comicsans.map (in /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]: Did you run mktexlsr?
```

huh?  yes, I did run mktexlsr, both as root and as myself.  I also confirmed that the file is there and readable.

```
# ls -l `kpsewhich comicsans.map`
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 root 1584 Dec 18  2013 /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/comicsans/comicsans.map
```

the file that it complains about is in the right place, and the hardcoded naming dispells any doubts.

---

font installation remains gray magic to me, even after decades of struggles.  the answer is probably obvious...but not to me.

advice appreciated.

/iaw

Comment: don't use `\font` ! just use standard latex size commands such a `\Huge`  or `\fontsize{1in}{2in}\selectfont`

Comment: If you are willing to use LuaLaTeX with fontspec, there is a font "Comic Relief" available from non-TeX sites under the Open Font License. Since it is a TrueType font, it is automatically scalable.

Comment: (I thought comic.ttf also was truetype.)  there is a reason to avoid lualatex:  time pdflatex book = 14.4 seconds.  time lualatex book = 21.9 seconds.  I am hoping the latter will manage to get to 16, and then I will switch.

Comment: Ah. Being retired, I can afford (21.9 - 14.4) = 7.5 seconds of my time, to get the additional functionality provided by LuaLaTeX. But I hadn't noticed comic.ttf. Perhaps I did not have a complete installation.

Comment: What does `kpsewhich updmap.cfg` give? You should use just `updmap-sys --enable Map=comicsans.map` or whatever - not the full path. But better is to edit the LOCAL config file. The `--enable` still works OK, though. However, I don't think that's the problem. Do you have the fonts themselves installed correctly? My guess is not.

Comment: probably not installed correctly, indeed.  kpsewhich gives `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg` .    Isn't installation just `cd /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config; unzip comicsans.tds.zip ; texhash` ?  what could have gone wrong??  I do want to point out that it works just fine at 12pt now.

Comment: That package does not include the actual fonts so it cannot possibly work fine unless you've installed the fonts earlier. You need to get the 2 TTF fonts, make sure they are named `comic.ttf` and `comicbd.ttf` and install them in a suitable place e.g. `<TEXMFLOCAL>/fonts/truetype/microsoft/comic/`. If you want to use oblique, you need to generate them. Also install the package you downloaded. Then run `mktexlsr`. Then run `updmap-sys` or edit the config and run it. Either way. Then you're done.

Comment: This is all explained in the package's documentation, by the way.

Comment: interesting.  it had worked with comicsans in the unmodified 12pt.  yet, kpsewhich did not see it.  but now, moving it right,`kpsewhich comic.ttf`: `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/truetype/microsoft/comic/comic.ttf`, but still no dice (even after a texhash).  same error.

Comment: RobtA: `Being retired, I can afford (21.9 - 14.4) = 7.5 seconds of my time`...but think about it.  how much of the rest of your time on earth can you afford on this ;-).

Comment: What does `kpsewhich rcomic8r.tfm` give? This file should be in something like `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/microsoft/comic/` and `kpsewhich` should know where it is.

Comment: indeed, it gives kpsewhich rcomic8r.tfm : `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/microsoft/comicsans/rcomic8r.tfm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came from ulrike fischer in [updmap: error when existing map file (fully qualified filename) is claimed to be missing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366539/updmap-error-when-existing-map-file-fully-qualified-filename-is-claimed-to-be?noredirect=1#comment903660_366539) .

```
# updmap-sys --enable Map=/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/comicsans/comicsans.map
```

does not work.  I need

```
# updmap-sys --enable Map=comicsans.map
```

then it works.  thanks.

Comment: @cfr told you this already two days ago: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365985/comic-sans-in-different-font-sizes-and-updmap-update-3#comment902350_365985

Comment: completely missed it.  getting very old...