# updmap: error when existing map file (fully qualified filename) is claimed to be missing?

Tags: fonts

relates to [comic sans in different font sizes, and updmap ? [update 3]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365985/comic-sans-in-different-font-sizes-and-updmap-update-3) .  I am trying to install comicsans.  in the process, I ran into a updmap oddity:

```
# updmap-sys --enable Map=/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/comicsans/comicsans.map
# cat /Users/ivo/Library/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
Map /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/comicsans/comicsans.map
# updmap
...
updmap [ERROR]: The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
updmap [ERROR]:     /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/comicsans/comicsans.map (in /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]: Did you run mktexlsr?
```

yes, I did run mktexlsr, and texhash, and ..., all early and often, and thus

```
# ls -l `kpsewhich comicsans.map`
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root 1584 Dec 18  2013 /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/comicsans/comicsans.map
```

still the same error.   does anyone understand what could be going on here?

/iaw

Comment: Why do you use absolute pathes? ( with --enable and so also in the cfg). This can only confuse kpathsea as there is no such path *in* the texmf.

Comment: hi ulrike---your answer is the solution.  do you want to make it an answer I can accept?